# Interaction potential energy between atoms in a pure metal and its alloys (source)

Tags: material-science

I'm studying the variations of Young's modulus in a metal and in its alloys:

$$E=\frac{1}{r^\text o} \space \left(\frac{d^{2}U}{dr^{2}}\right)_{r^\text o}$$

where $U$ is potential energy of interaction between two atoms and $r^\text o$ is the equilibrium distance between the two atoms.

Could you help me to find sources (books, articles) which show plot of $U(r)$ in the case of a pure metal and its alloys?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Accurate interatomic metal/alloy potentials $U$ are not merely a function of separation but rather they have complicated local density contributions (e.g., see the [embedded atom model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_atom_model)). So the plot $U(r)$  would require you to artificially impose a particular local configuration on each atom.

A common way to plot $U$ is to retain the equilibrium crystal structure and then scale the cell lattice parameter (but not allow the structure to relax) and then plot the average potential energy per atom. But I'm not sure whether this is what you want.

You can download various metal (and alloy) interatomic potentials from [NIST](https://www.ctcms.nist.gov/potentials/) and then use a molecular simulation code (e.g. LAMMPS) to build an atomic configuration and compute the potential energy (as described above). But this would be a lot of work if you don't know what you're doing...